# how to convert plugin (Created from existing jar) to maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I had created eclipse plugin from existing jar and I'm exporting all the packages as in below image.

1. All the packages
2. Exported packages.

[image]

Now I'm converting This plugin to Maven by using [configurator](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/discovery/directory-1.4.xml)

[image]

Now my plugin look like following and there no package is showing for export.

1. Now packages showing as folders
2. there is not package showing to export.

So every where I'm getting error because there is no class under this plugin in.

[image]

**Question**
How to convert plugin which are created by jar.?

Comment: did google search of "How to convert plugin which are created by jar." and got -> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html   .. new topic to me to add anything more

Comment: Hi Srinath, I'm not asking "How to convert plugin which are created by jar." that i know. I'm asking how to connvert this created plugin into maven project. My question is stated with "I had created eclipse plugin from existing jar". Please read it again. Thanks

Comment: Why would you export referenced jars in a Maven project? This doesn't make sense: downstream Maven projects will anyway inherit transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check:

1. Have you got the Maven Tycho Configurator installed? (Window->Preferences->Maven->Discovery->Open Catalog)
2. Have you overridden the default maven source folders in your pom file to match the Eclipse folder structure?

   ```
   <build>
     <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
     <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
   ```

Below is a link to an example pom file for a working maven build of Eclipse plugins. (Disclaimer: this is one of the projects I work on)

[Example parent pom file.](https://liquibase-eclipse-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com.svcdelivery.liquibase.eclipse/pom.xml)